# Firestore method is not being recognised

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Platform,
  Image,
  StatusBar,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
// import firebase, { firestore } from 'firebase';
// import db from '../components/config';

import 'firebase/firestore';
// import firebase from 'firebase/app';
// // import firebase from 'firebase'

// // import firebase from 'firebase/app';






export default class ScanScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      domState: 'normal',
      hasCameraPermissions: null,
      scanned: false,
    };
  }

  getCameraPermissions = async (domState) => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);

    this.setState({
      /*status === "granted" is true when user has granted permission
          status === "granted" is false when user has not granted the permission
        */
      hasCameraPermissions: status === 'granted',
      domState: domState,
      scanned: false,
    });
  };

  handleBarCodeScanned = async ({ type, data }) => {
    const { domState } = this.state;

    if (domState === 'bookId') {
      this.setState({
        bookId: data,
        domState: 'normal',
        scanned: true,
      });
    }
  };

  addProduct = async () => {
      await firestore()
      .collection('products')
      .doc('panadol')
      .add({
        expiry: '12/23/22',
        activeIngredient:'paracetemol',
      })
      
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Medication added!');
      });
  }




  render() {
    const { domState, scanned, bookId } = this.state;
    if (domState !== 'normal') {
      return (
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Header
          style={styles.header}
          backgroundColor={'#89CFF0'}
          centerComponent={{
            text: 'Pharmacy App',
            style: { color: '#fff', fontSize: 20 },
          }}
        />

        <Text style={styles.text}>Under Construction</Text>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder={'Type Barcode'}
          placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
          value={bookId}
          // onChangeText={()=> this.addProduct()}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
         onPress={() => this.addProduct()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={styles.orText}>OR</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => this.handleBarCodeScanned()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Scan</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#5653D4',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'pink',
    fontSize: 30,
  },

  imageIcon: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    marginLeft: 95,
  },

  header: {
    marginBottom: 100,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignContent: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 3,
    width: '57%',
    height: 50,
    marginLeft: 80,
    marginTop: 80,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#89CFF0',
    width: 250,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    marginLeft: 45,
    marginTop: 40,
    height: 50,
  },

  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    
  },

  orText: {
    marginLeft: 155,
    marginTop: 50,
    
  },
});
```

In my code, I have a method called add item in my Scan.js and in that method i have used firestore.collection and .add. I have called this function in a touchable opacity so when i run my code and try and click the button, it throws me this, *Scan.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: firestore* is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined [image]

I tried to update the version of firestore to 9.0.0 but it didn't work. The outcome of my app should be that when I press the done button, it should make a connection with my database and add a value in that field. [image]

Comment: Share code of whole file

Comment: Its because your not importing Firestore right also which version of Firebase you are using

Comment: Im using version 9.0.0 and i have already imported firebase.  
This is how i imported it:
import 'firebase/firestore';

Answer (score 0):

You're still using the version 8 syntax (Namespaced). You should use the **compat** libraries of the Firebase but I would suggest to refactor your code to version 9 sytax (Modular) as the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11).

For this, you should import your Firebase like this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

then initialize your Firebase App and Firestore:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
        // ...
    };
// Initialize Firebase App    
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Firestore
const db = app.firestore();
```

then use the variable `db` when accessing Firestore.

```
await db
    .collection('products')
    .doc('panadol')
    .add({
        expiry: '12/23/22',
        activeIngredient:'paracetemol',
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Medication added!');
    });
```

---

For more information, check out this documentations:

- [Upgrade from version 8 to the modular Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)
- [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8)

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for answering my question but when I followed the instructions you gave me, it popped up with an error saying,
 Home.js:27 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'firebase/compat/app'
and
VM6:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
which has already come up before. Any suggestions please

Comment: Install the latest firebase module. Do this: `npm install firebase@latest`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried installing the latest firebase in my terminal, but when I tried it, nothing happened. Also, in my Scan.js, I actually imported the db which made a difference. Please get back to me soon

Comment: Hi Marc. I've added another screen shot to my question. So this is the error that comes up when i use the compat libraries. I've tried multiple ways but the same error always pops up. Btw on snack it couldn't resolve the dependency, so i changed the version from version 9 to version 8. When doing this, it resolved the dependency. I then tried changing the version in VS code but it still gave me the same error.I appreciate your cooperation with me!

Comment: Have you already tried to delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` manually? If not, try to delete the 2 mentioned then modify your `package.json`, search for the `firebase` dependency and make it latest: `"firebase": "latest",`. After doing so, run `npm i`. Let me know if this fixed your issue.

Comment: Hey Marc. I'm actually a bit confused about what you said because I'm not sure if i should delete the whole folder or specific files inside of it. I tried following what you said but it just came up with SO many errors.

Comment: Yes. Delete the whole `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json`. Have you ran `npm install` after deleting the items above? Basically, what we're doing is removing all the existing dependencies and reinstalling it all again. Are you using yarn  or npm though?

Comment: Hi Marc. I'm using npm but I tried deleting all the files and reinstalling them but the same error popped up.What I actually found out is that when i first started my app, the firebase was not installed correctly so i tried installing by itself. Its kind of working but i definitely need your help. please answer as soon as possible. i appreciate your cooperation!